# disabling Cookies on phantomjs using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, phantomjs

I have searched for long time but I could not find how to disable cookies for phantomjs using selenium with python . I couldn't understand the documentation of phantomjs.Please someone help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation suggests this `driver.cookies_enabled = False`, you can use it.

Comment: Sorry i couldnt upvote you

Comment: Thanks for the help though

Comment: @user252718 you are welcome. Hope later you will do.

Comment: Sure but do mean that we should use it like in desired capabilities or a normal command

Comment: Just a command, not capabilities